# How to know if a user has a facebook account?

Tags: php, facebook, cookies

I need to know if the users of my website has logged to facebook in the past 30 days.

Can I know this through facebook cookies or in another way ?

Comment: Hopefully not, that would be really scary...

Comment: You could create a `<form>` that asks "Have you logged into facebook in the last 30 days?"

Comment: @brian_d, shouldn't that be an answer?

Comment: May I ask why you need to know this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a `<form>` that asks

1. "Do you have a facebook account?"
2. "If yes, have you logged into it in the last 30 days?"

**Edit:**
This is an interesting post on [Abusing HTTP Status Codes to Expose Private Information](https://grepular.com/Abusing_HTTP_Status_Codes_to_Expose_Private_Information)

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to check whether the user has logged into Facebook any time. What you can do is leverage the [CSS history hack](http://ha.ckers.org/weird/CSS-history-hack.html) to see whether the user has **visited** Facebook.

But that would still be kind of unethical...

Comment: It also wouldn't necessarily indicate that they visited in the past 30 days, and it doesn't mean they've logged in either.

Answer (score 2):

You could try checking the [Facebook Developer Tools](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web) for website integration.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your title question - actually it is possible to know if a user has facebook account, but only if he/she is logged in into facebook right now (even for those that never authorized your app before). You can do this by calling [`FB.getLoginStatus()`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus) and checking returned status. If it equals to `notConnected` - user is logged in into facebook right now.

Comment: and if he/she is not logged in to facebook what it return ?

Comment: @xRobot it will return `unknown`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read cookies from "other" sites. Actually you cannot read any cookies at all. The client/browser is *sending* you the cookies with their values. And they have no reason to send cookies to a web server which are associated to a total different site. If you want to know if a user have login into facebook you have to asked the facebook servers (if they have such an API and if you know the username)

Answer (score 0):

No - even if you knew their Facebook ID, had their email address, the user granted you every single [extended permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions), and also knew the user's favorite color and the names of all their pets, you *still* would not be able to determine what you're asking for.